# Find rows that have characters other than a plus (+) sign or number in a phone field

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find all rows in a phone column that have any character other than a plus sign (+) or numeric digit. It can be any character like slash, space, bracket, alphabet or any other character. The column has phone numbers, but may rows has space, brackets and slashes. I want to see those. Like:

```
+1.888.888.888
+1 (888) 888 8888
+1.8888888888
```

But theses are correct:

```
+18888888888
+33888888
```

and should not show.

I tried:

```
SELECT `phone` FROM `listings` WHERE `phone` NOT IN (SELECT `phone` FROM `listings` WHERE `phone` REGEXP '^+\d')
```

And

```
SELECT `phone` FROM `listings` WHERE `phone` NOT IN (SELECT `phone` FROM `listings` WHERE `phone` REGEXP '^+[0-9]')
```

Error: `Error in query (1139): Got error 'nothing to repeat at offset 1' from regexp`

Comment: You could start by writing what you want... And then doing a NOT IN e.g. SELECT number FROM list WHERE number NOT IN (SELECT number FROM list WHERE number REGEXP '^+\d' Have a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the track with the second one. But all the characters of a class have to be in the square brackets. To negate the class the caret has to go in there as well, as first character. Outside it matches the beginning of the string.

There's no need to use `IN` here though. You can filter directly with a `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT phone
       FROM listings
       WHERE phone REGEXP '[^0-9+]';
```